# How to compare multiple lists elements with respect to their position?

Tags: python, list, string-comparison

I have multiple lists of strings. I need to compare the content of each position of the list to same position in the other lists. Then compute how many are the same (excluding the "0"). The lists have the same length. Here is an example:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "f", "0"]
list2 = ["a", "b", "e", "f", "0"]
list3 = ["a", "0", "c", "f", "0"]
```

So only `"a"` and `"f"` that are common in the same position over all the lists ("0" is not counted), then I need an output equal to 2.

I tried the following strategy but it fails as it only compares two by two, and could modify the np.sum so that it compares all the lists.

`All_lists` contains all the lists.

```
def scores(All_lists):
    score_lin = []
    score_ = 0
    for j in range(len(All_lists[0])):
        score_lin.append(
            np.sum(
                All_lists[j] == All_lists[j+1])
                - min(
                    np.count_nonzero(All_lists[j] == '0'),                 
                    np.count_nonzero(All_rg_lists[j+1] == '0')
                )
            )

    score_lin = [
        item 
        for item in score_lin 
        if item > 0
    ]
    score_ = sum(score_lin)

    return score_
```

EDIT: for list of lists.

```
list_ = [
    [
        ["a", "b", "c", "f", 0], 
        ["a", "b", "e", "f", 0], 
        ["a", 0, "c", "f", 0]
    ], 
    [
        ["b", "x", "c", "f", 0],  
        ["a", "b", "c", "f", 0],  
        ["a", "b", "c", "f", 0]
    ],
]
```

Considering the list of list "list". I need to compare `list[0][0] = ["a","b","c","f",0]` to `list[1][0] = ["b","x","c","f",0]` and compute the number of similar elements in the two lists, then do the same for `list[0][1]` and `list[1][1]...` In this example the expected output is 8.

nb: the length of list could be greater than 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to zip these 3 lists together and `set()` to find duplicates:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "f", "0"]
list2 = ["a", "b", "e", "f", "0"]
list3 = ["a", "0", "c", "f", "0"]

print(
    sum(
        len(set(i))==1 and i[0]!='0' 
        for i in zip(list1, list2, list3)
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
2
```

EDIT: For lists in lists:

```
l = [
    [
        ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ],
    [
        ['s2', 's1', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ],
    [
        ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
]

from pprint import pprint

total_sum = 0
for item in zip(*l):
    pprint(item)
    s = sum(
        len(set(i))==1 and i[0]!=0
        for i in zip(*item)
    )
    total_sum += s
    print(s)
    print('*' * 80)

print('Total sum =', total_sum)
```

Prints:

```
(['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['s2', 's1', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
2
********************************************************************************
(['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['s2', 's1', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
2
********************************************************************************
(['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['s2', 's1', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
2
********************************************************************************
(['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['s2', 's1', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
2
********************************************************************************
(['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['s2', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0])
2
********************************************************************************
Total sum = 10
```

Comment: Thank you! would it be possible to extended for an list of lists ? It arises a TypeError: Unhashable type: 'list'!

Comment: Thank you, in fact the edited version works well when all the elements inside the of the list are the same. In my case it's not. for example:   [[['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [['s2', 's1', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ['s2', 's1', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ['s2', 's1', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ['s2', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's3', 's3', 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: @imnou Please edit your question and put there data you are working with + expected output. It's hard to figure out the solution without it.

Comment: For your edited version, instead i need an output of 8, as there is "c" and "f" for the l[0][0] and l[1][0], "a" ,"b","f" for l[0][1] and l[1][1], "a","c","f" in  l[0][2] and l[1][2],

Comment: @imnou I must admin it's hard to understand. Edit your question and put sample input + expected output with explication there. It's hard to read it in comments.

Comment: Yeees it's exactely what i'm looking for. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a generic function which can accept any number of lists, then you can use this,

```py
def score(All_lists):
    z = zip(*All_lists) # zip lists together to make list of tuples
    z = [t for t in z if '0' not in t] # remove all '0' entries
    score_list = [1 for t in z if len(set(t))==1]
    return sum(score_list)
```

For these input lists,

```
list1=["a","b","c","f","0"]
list2=["a","b","e","f","0"]
list3=["a","0","c","f","0"]
All_lists = [list1, list2, list3]
```

Calling `score(All_lists)` returns `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
list1=["a","b","c","f","0"]
list2=["a","b","e","f","0"]
list3=["a","0","c","f","0"]

print(len([len(set(x)) for x in list(zip(list1,list2,list3)) if len(set(x)) == 1 and x[0] != '0']))
```

Output:

```
 2
```

Answer (score 0):

what about :

```
sum(a == b == c  for a, b, c  in zip(list1, list2, list3) if a != '0')
```